# Is it possible to run metasploitable on a raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, metasploit

i was just wondering, is it possible to run metasploitable on a raspberry pi B+ to use as a target? i have looked for about an hour now and i cannot find any references to running the OS on the pi. if you can find anything, or any downloads for metasploitable for the pi, please link them :)

Comment: see http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/raspberry-pi-recipes#Installing_Metasploit_on_the_Raspberry_Pi - this is about as close as you can get - though is for the first model of the pi

Comment: thanks Takarii but im looking at running metasploit on my laptop then using my raspberry pi as a target :/

Comment: my appologies, i misread the question.